# jquery response in displaying the view page through post

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

jquery

```
var js={"employer":$employer,"district":$district,"state":$state};

     $.post(url+"/beneficarydetailsdisp",js,function(data){
                                        $("#noofbeneficiaryplacedtable").html(data.result);
            },"json");
```

I am able to load the view page but it is displayed in firebug not on the browser page?

firebug response

```
{"result":"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-\/\/W3C\/\/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional\/\/EN\" \"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/TR\/xhtml1\/DTD\/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\r\n<html crossriderapp3491=\"true\" xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xhtml\"><head id=\"ctl00_Head1\">\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text\/html; charset=UTF-8\"><title>\r\n\tJob Placement\r\n<\/title>\r\n<!-- Page layout -->\r\n<link href=\"http:\/\/localhost\/******\/\/css\/StyleSheet.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text\/css\ .....contd"
```

controller

```
$employer ="Hass Enterprises";
    $district ="ADILABAD";
    $state ="ANDHRA PRADESH";
    $data['noofbeneficiaryplaceddetails']=$this->homemodel->getnoofbeneficiaryplaceddetails($employer,$district,$state);    

     $str=$this->load->view('noofbeneficiaryplaced',$data,true);
     $value=array(
            'result'=>$str

        );
        echo json_encode($value);}
```

i am not able to load the view ? what is the problem with the code

Comment: Loading a `DOCTYPE`, an `html` tag, a `head` tag, and all the other document-level stuff into an element in an existing DOM is probably invalid HTML and would result in undefined behavior.

Comment: You say that you "see it in Firebug" but not on the page.  I see no actual _visible_ elements being returned by the response.  What are you _expecting_ to see on the page?

Comment: i able to see the view in my firebug but not on the browser response returns the full view in that page...i guess some problem in $.post as the controller doesnt load too and just displays in the firebug column but not on the page

Comment: Have you done any debugging on this?  Is the JavaScript code in question being called at all?  Does Firebug indicate that it sends a POST to the server?  Does that POST contain the information you expect it to contain?  Does the server resource see that same information?  Does the server resource process the request as you expect?  Does Firebug show the expected response from the server resource?  Does the AJAX response handler in the JavaScript code get executed in your debugging?  Does it modify the DOM as expected?  There is a _lot_ of information you're not sharing with us.

Comment: And, again, you're trying to render invalid HTML.  So if it's not rendering as expected then your first step should probably be to use _valid_ HTML.

Comment: YUP !!i have done debugging it is able to post and get the response too

Comment: nope if a add a valid html too it is displayed in the firebug column not on the page?

Comment: Vaguely describing a different result doesn't make for good debugging.  If you're reproduced the issue with valid HTML, please show the *full code* that reproduces the issue.  You keep claiming that you're doing everything correctly, but you haven't actually shown us what you're doing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13575/discussion-between-dude-and-david)